# Computing PGP ed25519 and curve25519 keygrips?

Tags: public-key, keys, pgp, ed25519

There are public key algorithmic differences for how PGP computes fingerprints and keygrips. For the v4 protocol, fingerprints are not exclusively computed from public keys while keygrips are. RFC 4880 makes no mention about keygrips.

After digging into code at $10$ different places in the [libgcrypt](https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/master/tests/keygrip.c), it is still a mystery as to how PGP keygrips are computed for ed25519 and curve25519.

Fortunately, the keygrip.c provides the two normative example test vectors:

```
 1. ed25519: 
    publicKey = 773E72848C1FD5F9652B29E2E7AF79571A04990E96F2016BF4E0EC1890C2B7DB,
    keygrip   = 9DB6C64A38830F4960701789475520BE8C821F47

 2. cv25519: 
    publicKey = 918C1733127F6BF2646FAE3D081A18AE77111C903B906310B077505EFFF12740,
    keygrip   = 0F89A565D3EA187CEA39332398F5D480677DF49C
```

Can someone provide the operations on the public keys prior to the sha1 hash that creates that creates the keygrip output? (Thanks in advance.)

Comment: https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/master/cipher/ecc-eddsa.c#L191 "else if (buf[0] == 0x40)" is around five levels down from the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to stay out of **libgcrypt** repository and instead remain focused within the higher level **gnupg** repository, specifically [**gnupg/g10/keyid.c**](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/g10/keyid.c#L980). The **keygrip_from_pk()** function is what makes the public key algo specific calls to build the S expressions that feeds the lower level [**gcry_pk_get_keygrip()**](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-S_002dexpressions.html) function used to calculate the binary keygrip **array** that is turned into a hex keygrip by the calling function **hexkeygrip_from_pk()**.

An analysis of the code just described above plus code at [**keygrip_ed25519(vk)**](https://github.com/romanz/trezor-agent/blob/master/libagent/gpg/protocol.py#L125) and [**keygrip_curve25519(vk)**](https://github.com/romanz/trezor-agent/blob/master/libagent/gpg/protocol.py#L138) should facilitate a programming language means for constructing **ed25519** and **cv25519** keygrips.

Answer (score 0):

Keygrips **are not part of PGP** at all, they're just an implementation detail of GnuPG's key storage architecture specifically (which uses a common key store for PGP, S/MIME, and SSH).

As you saw, GnuPG uses *libgcrypt* for cryptographic operations, and the keygrip calculation can be found in [cipher/pubkey.c](https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/355f5b7f69075c010fe33aa5b10ac60c08fae0c7/cipher/pubkey.c#L618) where it's just a SHA-1 hash of the public key's parameters.